# How to soft delete related records when soft deleting a parent record in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, soft-delete

I have this invoices table that which has the following structure

```
id | name | amount | deleted_at
2    iMac   1500   | NULL
```

and a payments table with the following structure

```
id | invoice_id | amount | deleted_at
2    2            1000   | NULL
```

Invoice Model

```
class Invoice extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

here's the code to delete the invoice

```
public function cance(Request $request,$id)
{
    $record = Invoice::findOrFail($id);
    $record->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'OK',
    ]);
}
```

Payments model

```
class Payment extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

The softDelete on Invoice table works perfectly but its related records (payments) still exists.How do I delete them using softDelete?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Eloquent** doesn't provide automated deletion of related objects, therefore you'll need to write some code yourself. Luckily, it's pretty simple.

**Eloquent models** fire different events in different stages of model's life-cycle like creating, created, deleting, deleted etc. - you can read more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events. What you need is a listener that will run when **deleted** event is fired - this listener should then delete all related objects.

You can register model listeners in your model's **boot()** method. The listener should iterate through all payments for the invoice being deleted and should delete them one by one. Bulk delete won't work here as it would execute SQL query directly bypassing model events.

This will do the trick:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
  protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function ($invoice) {
      $invoice->payments()->delete();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work!

FatalErrorException in Invoice.php line 18:
Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::boot() non static in class App\Models\Invoice

Comment: Fixed, the function was missing the static modifier

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks a lot! Does this cause any performance issues when soft deleting say about 100 records?

Comment: You have to fetch all of them and then save each of them, so it's additional 101 queries... In such case you could set the deleted_at manually for related models, this will be less clean but will run only one SQL query. I'll update the answer in a second

Comment: I know this is old, but i would really recommend to use of observers to achieve this.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

You can go one of 2 ways with this.

The simplest way would be to override Eloquents `delete()` method and include the related models as well e.g.:

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->payments()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

The above method should work just find but it seems a little bit dirty and I'd say it's not the preferred method within the community.

The cleaner way (IMO) would be to tap into Eloquents events e.g.:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($invoice) { 
         $invoice->payments()->delete();

    });
}
```

Either (but not both) of the above methods would go in your `Invoice` model.
Also, I'm assuming that you have your relationships set up in your model, however, I'm not sure if you allow multiple payments for one invoice. Either way you might need to change the `payments()` in the examples to whatever you've named the relationship in your invoice model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Calling delete() on payments relation directly will bypass the model and won't trigger the SoftDelete on related models. They will be removed from the database. In order to make thek soft-deleted you need to call delete() on each of related models.

Comment: You are also missing the return statement in your overridden delete method - it should do "return parent::delete();", otherwise you lose the value that would be returned from delete() if you hadn't overwritten it.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, I've just tested to make sure and YES you can use soft delete on a relationship!

Comment: True, just checked the code. Good to know for the future :)

Comment: does it guarantee transaction @RossWilson

Comment: @TomonsoEjang What do you mean sorry? As in will it actually delete them? Or will it work if wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: @RossWilson on deleting the event of a model. Can it happen that the related record is deleted and the original model to be deleted failed to be deleted (here deleted means updated the deleted_at to some timestamp)

Comment: @ TomonsoEjang  If you wrap the call in a transaction it should still behave the same way. There isn't any asynchronous behaviour so it will still start the transaction, run the code in the models and then end the transaction...if there is an issue then the transaction will be rolled back.

Answer (score 8):

I know you asked this question a long time ago but I found [this package](https://github.com/Askedio/laravel5-soft-cascade) to be very simple and straightforward.

Or you can use [this package](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes) it's useful too.

**Remember** to install the right version depending on your laravel version.

You must install it via composer:

```
 composer require askedio/laravel5-soft-cascade ^version
```

In second package:

```
 composer require iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes
```

Register the service provider in your config/app.php.

you can read the docs on the GitHub page.

If you delete a record this package recognizes all of its children and soft-delete them as well.

If you have another relationship in your child model use its trait in that model as well. its so much easier than doing it manually.

The second package has the benefit of deleting grandchildren of the model. in some cases, I say its a better approach.

Comment: I used second package and it worked great for delete() but can I make it work for restore also?

Answer (score 2):

**If the relationship of your database does not go any further than only one layer,** then you could simply use Laravel events to handle your soft-deletes within the Model `boot()` method as follow:

```
<?php
//...

    protected static boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($invoice) { 
             $invoice->payments()->delete();

        }); 
    }
```

**If, however, your structure goes deeper than only one layer**, you will have to tweak that piece of code.

Let's say for example you don't want to remove the payments of an invoice but rather the whole payment history of a given user.

```
<?php

// ...

class Invoice extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Holds the methods names of Eloquent Relations
     * to fall on delete cascade or on restoring
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $relations_to_cascade = ['payments']; 

    protected static boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($resource) {
            foreach (static::$relations_to_cascade as $relation) {
                foreach ($resource->{$relation}()->get() as $item) {
                    $item->delete();
                }
            }
        });

        static::restoring(function($resource) {
            foreach (static::$relations_to_cascade as $relation) {
                foreach ($resource->{$relation}()->get() as $item) {
                    $item->withTrashed()->restore();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

// ...

class User extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Holds the methods names of Eloquent Relations 
     * to fall on delete cascade or on restoring
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $relations_to_cascade = ['invoices']; 

    protected static boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($resource) {
            foreach (static::$relations_to_cascade as $relation) {
                foreach ($resource->{$relation}()->get() as $item) {
                    $item->delete();
                }
            }
        });

        static::restoring(function($resource) {
            foreach (static::$relations_to_cascade as $relation) {
                foreach ($resource->{$relation}()->get() as $item) {
                    $item->withTrashed()->restore();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
    }
}
```

This paradigm ensures Laravel to follow the rabbit hole no matter how deep it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model Observers as well:

```
php artisan make:Observer InvoiceOberser --model=Invoice
```

It will create a new file in /app/Observers/InvoiceObserver.php with the following methods:

- created
- updated
- deleted
- restored
- forceDeleted

You just need to update the deleted method to this:

```
public function deleted(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $invoice->payments()->delete();
}
```

And finally in /app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php add this lines:

```
// On the top
use App\Models\Invoice;
use App\Observers\InvoiceObserver;

// On boot method
Invoice::observe(InvoiceObserver::class);
```