# Updating related model attributes on delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Using Laravel 5.1, I want to soft delete a `category`, which should automatically set attributes on its related models, `question`.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163509/how-to-soft-delete-related-records-when-soft-deleting-a-parent-record-in-laravel) recommends binding delete event on the model:

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $category->delete();
}
```

Then...

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($category) { 
        $category->questions()->delete();
    });
}
```

This works. But I don't want to delete the related questions, rather set an attribute on each:

```
    static::deleting(function($category) { 
        $category->questions()->is_published = 'no';
    });
```

This doesn't seem to work. There is no error, but also no queries are fired in my query logger. Why is `delete()` fired on each related model, but not attribute changes?

The way I get this to work now is as such, but it's not clean:

```
    static::deleting(function($category) {
        $questions = $category->questions()->get();
        foreach($questions as $q) {
            $q->is_published = 'no';
            $q->save();
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you want to set attribute you will need to save it. You can use local scope in question model to fire one query changing all questions with a specific category id

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

In your question model

```php
public function setIsPublished($isPublished) {
    $this->is_published = $isPublished;
    return $this;
}
```

And change

```
static::deleting(function($category) {
    $questions = $category->questions()->get();
    foreach($questions as $q) {
        $q->is_published = 'no';
        $q->save();
    }
});
```

to

```php
 static::deleting(function($category) {
    foreach($category->questions as $q) {
        $q->setIsPublished('no')->save();
    }
});
```

Comment: I personnaly prefer to use 0 or 1, which can be translated to no or yes in any language